# Kafka topic and multiple instances of a microservice

Tags: apache-kafka, microservices, messaging, autoscaling, idempotent

This is more of a system design question.

Let's assume I have a microservice architecture and I have **X instances** of `Service B` (to load-balance HTTP requests to the service). But, `Service B` is also a consumer on some Kafka topic. How can I avoid processing the same message **X times** (X is the number of instances of `Service B`)? `at least once` could be fine if processing is idempotent. It doesn't need to be `exactly once`, but cannot be `X times` .

Service A could be an Order Service. It produces messages about user making an order to **Orders topic**.

Service B could be a Payment Service. It consumes messages from **Orders topic** to charge the user.

Paying for an order could be an idempotent operation. But still, if I have 10 instances of Payment Service, I don't want to waste CPU and IO for doing something 10 times.

Even if partitioning is the answer, what if we have more instances of a particular microservice than partitions?

Answer (score 7):

**Kafka consumer group**

When you have `x` instances of a service and you want messages to be consumed by the service only once, this is something the **consumer group** concept of Kafka takes care of.

Essentially you need to specify a **common kafka consumer group ID** for your service instances, and then kafka will take care of assigning partitions of the topic to different consumer instances of your service such that no message would be consumed twice by your service.

There would be a config for consumer group ID among the kafka consumer configs in the kafka consumer library that you're using. You just need to ensure that a single set of your service instances are assigned the same value of consumer group ID for that config.

**Explanation with an example**

If your service `B` has `10` instances, you specify a **common kafka consumer group ID** for all the 10 instances, say `serviceBConsumerGroup`. When consumption from a kafka topic with 10 partitions begins, kafka takes care of assigning the partitions of the topic to all the instances of the consumer group `serviceBConsumerGroup`. So essentially it would assign each partition to each instance (when there are 10 instances of the service and 10 partitions of the topic). If there are 5 instances of the service and 10 partitions of the kafka topic, Kafka would assign 2 partitions to every instance for consumption.

**Some references to read about Kafka consumer group:**

- [Kafka: The Definitive Guide](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/kafka-the-definitive/9781491936153/ch04.html)
- [Confluent kafka doc](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/consumer.html#consumer-groups)
- [Apache kafka doc](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#design_consumerposition)

Comment: When you have x instances of a service and you want messages to be consumed by the service only once, this is something the consumer group concept of Kafka takes care of.-- This is not true..Even if you have x instances and only one consumer, then also no message get processed again because it works on consumer offset.After processing message the consumer commit the offset for that message so that message won't get processed again. And question is about the reprocessing messages not parallel processing of messages.

Comment: @Vaibs Kafka consumers always work on consumer offsets, that is to track which messages have been consumed by a consumer group. And if there are x instances of a service with all of them having unique consumer group, then messages of a topic can be consumed x times by the service. The OP's question is "How can I avoid processing the same message X times", and that is what assigning same consumer group to all the instances achieves.

Comment: I think it's completely opposite to what you are saying. If I have 10 consumers belong to a unique single consumer group and messages get processed again then what's the use of the consumer group.And AFAIK every consumer group comes with unique ID. Consumer group is come in picture when we add parallelism or some other consumer want's do some other operation on that topic data.For e.g. Consumer A do calculation on order data and Consumer B do send notification on basis of order data Please check this blog https://dzone.com/articles/kafka-consumer-architecture-consumer-groups-and-su..

Comment: @Vaibs You misunderstood me, when I said "x instances of a service with all of them having unique consumer group", that means the consumer group is unique for every instance. That means, the consumer group of every instance is different. Then messages will be consumed x times. You misunderstood the word `unique` with `common`. They are opposites.

Comment: Please check the references that I have added to my answer if you're having any confusion.

Comment: A single consumer group ID corresponds to a consumer group. And how many instances are part of the consumer group depends on the consumer group ID that is assigned to each instance of the service(kafka consumer). If x instances of the service have a common consumer group ID, then messages from the topic are consumed only once by the set of service instances. And if x instances of the service have unique consumer group IDs, then messages from the topic are consumed x times by the set of service instances (essentially because there are x consumer groups formed).

Comment: The above point I have already mentioned in my comment. As per question, Payment Service is having only one purpose to process the data, so only signle consumber group works. Also in question it's not mentioned that, they are using autogenerated group.id property. Because group.id is mandatory field. Also check this answer once. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43118671/kafka-consumer-default-group-id

Answer (score 2):

As per the question,

You don't need to worry about the reprocessing of the same message even if you have multiple instances of service. Because Kafka works on consumer offset, if you once read the message, we commit the offset for that message so that message won't be available for that consumer(group).

Let's take an example,

Order service publishes the message on Order topic and payment service subscribed to it. And we have 10 instances of Payment services. In this case, let's consider message 1 get's consumed by the Payment service instance 1 (which belongs to the default consumer group if you don't define it explicitly). After consuming message 1, the Payment service instance 1 commits the offset for that message (at consumer group level)and it will be considered as the message has been processed successfully. So Payment service instance 2/anyother instance will only pick the messages which offset as not committed.

As per @Madhu's answer, it is for faster and parallelism of processing the messages. If you have 10 instances of Payment services and wanted to access and process messages fastly then you can add more consumer under consumer group(But need to consider the partitions count for the Order Topic because if Order topic has 4 partitions and we defined 5 consumer then 1 consumer always in idle state unless any other consumer goes down).